# Do you need to unit test CDK against the synthesized Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-cdk

If you are creating custom CDK Constructs, I do understand that it makes sense to test if the synthesized template is correct.

But let's say you are using the core CDK to setup your infrastructure. Does it makes sense to make unit tests asserting against the synthesized Cloudformation template? To me, that feels like you are testing the CDK synth process not your CDK code.

This article somewhat touches on the same point: [link](https://theburningmonk.com/2023/06/no-you-dont-need-to-test-every-line-of-your-cdk-application/#:%7E:text=The%20official%20CDK%20documentation%20includes%20some%20unit%20testing%20examples%20that%20show%20how%20you%20can%20validate%20the%20synthesized%20CloudFormation%20template.) .

But I worry I might be missing something since AWS themselves recommend testing against the synthesized templates.

Answer (score 2):

The CDK [assertions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.assertions-readme.html) module lets you assert against the synthesized template output.  Typically, the goal is to test your business logic or apply a governance standard.  You don't need to test whether the CDK has done its job.  You are testing whether you have properly parameterized the resources to fit your use case or policies.

For instance, as a security check, you may want to assert your stack has no Internet Gateway:

```js
import { Template } from "aws-cdk-lib/assertions";
 
const template = Template.fromStack(myStack);

test("No IGW", () => {
    template.resourceCountIs("AWS::EC2::InternetGateway", 0);
});
```

Or you might wish to test that if you are deploying to a prod account, a given resource's removal policy is `cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN`, but if you are deploying to a test account, the removal policy is `DESTROY`.

---

N.B. Unit tests are not your only option for governance checks.  The [cdk-nag](https://github.com/cdklabs/cdk-nag) tool can help you apply rules (e.g. don't use AWS managed IAM policies, don't use wildcards in IAM permissions) at synth-time.  [AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/WhatIsConfig.html) can check for compliance with governance rules on your deployed resources.